# How to move files to year/month/day folders based on timestamp in java

Tags: java, date, timestamp, filesystems

I have files with timestamp as its fileName. I want to move these files into years/month/day folder based on it timestamp which is nothing but the fileName.

Eg: fileName=2017-11-2_23-59-59(YYYY-mm-dd_HH-MM-SS). Now I want to move this file to 2017 folder and inside that folder 11 (month) folder and inside that 2 (date) folder and if the folder is not present create one.

So all days folders should be inside a month folder and months folders should be inside year folder. This is the folder structure i need.

Comment: This seems reasonably straightforward.  Which part are you struggling with?

Comment: Well, parse the file name, create the directories if they don't exist yet, then move the file. All these are quite simple tasks. But you'll need to do a bit of research, read Java IO tutorials, javadoc. This is part of a developer's job.

Comment: Is it given that this happens in one time zone or at one offset from UTC only? I’m slightly uncomfortable not knowing the zone offsets of those timestamps. Or maybe they are all UTC? And it’s OK to store the files by date in UTC?

Comment: This Question is too broad for Stack Overflow. Questions here must be narrowly focused on a particular programming problem, not asking for a tutorial on a sequence of common programming chores. **I voted to close.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be helpful for you:

```
String file = form.getFile().getOriginalFilename();
String[] dateParts = file.split("-");
String year = dateParts[0]; 
String month = dateParts[1]; 
String day = dateParts[2]; 
String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C://Users//pandeyv//Desktop//"+year+"//"+month+"//"+day+"//";
File dir = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER);
if (!dir.exists())
    dir.mkdirs();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you have a `Path` to your file somehow. Maybe you use `Paths.get()` to get one. Or to get a path to the folder (directory) holding the files and then `Files.list()` to obtain a path to each file in the folder. From your `Path`, get the name of the file (e.g., `2017-11-2_23-59-59`).

I recommend you use `DateTimeFormatter` and `LocalDateTime` to parse the file name into a date-time. When specifying a format pattern for your `DateTimeFormatter`, be aware that it is case sensitive. You need a pattern like `uuuu-M-d_H-mm-ss`; please finetune yourself.

Build a new `Path` for your destination folder (e.g., `2017/11/02`). Either get year, month and day from your date-time using methods `getYear`, `getMonthValue` and `getDayOfMonth`. Or use formatters to get these as strings rather than `int`s. I would prefer to have two-digit names for all month and date folders (`09` for September and `02` for the 2nd of the month). In some cases this will help you get the correct chronological sorting; however, you know your requirement, I don’t. Again, use `Paths.get()` to build the path. Then use `Files.createDirectories()` to make sure your nested folders are created in the file system (if they are already there, the method does nothing and just returns the path).

Use `Path.resolve()` to append your file name to the folder path. Finally `Files.move()` will move your file to the destination folder.